# sed with special characters

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed

I have this line that I want to use sed on:

```
--> ASD = $start ( *.cpp ) <--
```

where $start is not a varaiable, I want to use sed on it and replace all this line with:

```
ASD = $dsadad ( .cpp )
```

How can I make sed ignore special charactars, I tried adding back slash before special characters, but maybe I got it wrong, can some one show me an example?

Here is what i want :

```
sed 's/CPPS = \$(shell ls | grep \*\.cpp )/somereplace/' Makefile
```

Comment: `ls | grep *.cpp` is better written `$(wildcard *.cpp)` in GNU Make, or `ls *.cpp` if you really insist on using `ls` ([but don't](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sed 's/\$start/\$dsadad/g' your_file
>> ASD = $dsadad ( *.cpp ) 

sed 's/\*//g' your_file
>> ASD = $start ( .cpp )
```

To follow your edit :

```
sed -i 's/ASD = \$start ( \*.cpp )/ASD = \$dsadad ( .cpp )/' somefile
>> ASD = $dsadad ( .cpp )
```

Add the -i (--inplace) to edit the input file.

Comment: it is correct , but i need to add -i or else it will paste the file and will not replace, do you know why is that?

Answer (score 4):

Backslash works fine. `echo '*.cpp' | sed 's/\*//'` => `.cpp`

If you're in a shell, you might need to double escape `$`, since it's a special character both for the shell (variable expansion) and for sed (end of line)

`echo '$.cpp' | sed "s/\\$//"` or `echo '$.cpp' | sed 's/\$//'` => '.cpp'

Do not escape `(` or `)`; that will actually make them them special (groups) in sed. Some other common characters include `[` `]` `\` `.` `?`

This is how to escape your example:

```
sed 's/ASD = \$start ( \*\.cpp )/ASD = $dsadad ( .cpp )/' somefile
```

Comment: but i have $ also and ( and ) , are they also special characters ?

Comment: sed 's/ASD = \$start ( \*\.cpp )/ASD = $dsadad ( .cpp )/' somefile not working

Comment: this `echo -n 'ASD = $start ( *.cpp )'  | sed 's/\(.*\)start\(.*\)\*\(.*\)/\1dsadad\2\3/'` works for me

Comment: @shd You forgot the backslash at the first `*`.

Comment: -i makes sed to the replacements in file, ie write them. Without -i, sed writes to stdout.

Comment: In my case, I should escape double-quote _"_ but not _<_ and _>_ :  `echo '<table>, atablesir' | sed "s/<table>/<table class=\"table table-striped\">/g"`

Answer (score 1):

The chacters `$`,`*`,`.` are special for regular expressions, so they need to be escaped to be taken literally.

```
sed 's/ASD = \$start ( \*\.cpp )/ASD = \$dsadad ( .cpp )/' somefile
```

Comment: Yes, the left-hand side is a regular expression, and the right-hand side is a string. On *both sides*, perl will perform variable interpolation. So this actually a bug in my answer: perl will substitute`$dsadad` with the variable's value. the `$` should be escaped on both sides.

Comment: Okay. I've edited your answer to not have that bug, then.

Comment: oh, wait, I was thinking about perl. sed does not do variables. The unescaped version is OK. The edited version is OK too. The single quotes around the sed body will prevent *the shell* from substituting any variables, so the `$` on the left-hand side is escaped only to prevent its special regular expression meaning.

Answer (score 0):

I have one use case where I have to replace a text with a variable, that variable contains a special symbol,
like (xyz-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com). This `@` symbol was creating an issue. So I found this solution useful.

```
SERVICE_ACCOUNT="xyz-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
sed -i 's/DEVOPS_SERVICE_ACCOUNT/'${SERVICE_ACCOUNT}'/g' file.txt
```