# Jenkins - parametrise .php file

Tags: php, yii, jenkins, parameters, parameter-passing

I am configuring Jenkins in order to make it build my project.
It checks out source code, installs all required libs etc..

My application configuration is stored in `params.php` file (Yii 1.x style), it looks the following way:

```
return array(
    'dbHost' => 'dbHostValuePlaceholder',
    'dbPasssword' => 'dbPasswordValuePlaceholder',
    /* other values go here */
);
```

Obviously I need to replace **dbPasswordValuePlaceholder** with password that I set when starting parametrised build.

Current solution I've found is running this as shell command:

```
sed -i s/dbPasswordValuePlaceholder/$DB_PASSWORD/g $WORKSPACE/protected/config/params.php
```

where **$DB_PASSWORD** is corresponding variable.

This solution work perfectly with simple strings, but password may look like `a1@2";$&^*&-=+/*-:'/.,,,,,,,,^^^^^` - in this case **sed** fails because of unescaped characters.

I have searched for different Jenkins plugins, but there are only plugins that work with other formats like .xml etc, and neither works with .php files.

I need to avoid moving my config values out of *.php* file to some other format.

Is there a way to replace the described tokens in *.php* file with build parameters values ?

**UPDATE**

As @Stanjer recommended, I have tried to set param value to:

```
a1@2";$&^*&-=+/*-:\'/.,,,,,,,,^^^^^
```

So, in this case, the following code in PHP would be right, valid:

```
'universalPassword' => 'a1@2";$&^*&-=+/*-:\'/.,,,,,,,,^^^^^',
```

It does not help, here is output:

```
[build.int] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson642312569695847678.sh
+ sed -i s/defaultUniversalPassword/a1@2";$&^*&-=+/*-:\'/.,,,,,,,,^^^^^/g /var/www/build.int/protected/config/params.php
sed: -e expression #1, char 43: unknown option to `s'
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Hey, could you please give an example of the stringthat doesn't work? This one inside a question couldn't be valid, as you can't add such string inside `'dbPasssword' => 'dbPasswordValuePlaceholder'`, as then you php code would be invalid. I tried `'dbPasssword' => 'a1@2";$&^*&-=+/*-:/.,^^^^^',` and it works perfectly. I mean you can't have single quotes inside single quotes..

Comment: @Stanjer Here it is:  a1@2";$&^*&-=+/*-:'/.,,,,,,,,^^^^^

Comment: sorry, I have edited my question above

Comment: Then it's pretty simple, please see the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the updated question.

In your case you should show that it's already escaped by providing it as `$'string'`.

So the command will look like:

`$ sed s#dbPasswordValuePlaceholder#$'"a1@2";$&^*&-=+/*-:\'/.,,,^^^"'#g test.php`

and output will be:

```
<?php

return array(
    'dbHost' => 'dbHostValuePlaceholder',
    'dbPassword' => '"a1@2";$dbPasswordValuePlaceholder^*dbPasswordValuePlaceholder-=+/*-:'/.,,,,,,,,^^^^^"',
    /* other values go here */
);

?>
```

If using with variable:

`export NEWPASS=$'"a1@2";$&^*&-=+/*-:\'/.,,,^^^"'`

`sed "s#dbPasswordValuePlaceholder#$NEWPASS#g" test.php`

Comment: It's still unclear how to insert a variable value inside `$ sed s#dbPasswordValuePlaceholder#$'"a1@2";$&^*&-=+/*-:\'/.,,,^^^"'#g` statement. It treats it like string, and does not insert a var value there.

Comment: It produces output like this:

+ export NEWPASS=WsdsadasO^w
+ sed s#defaultUniversalPassword#WsdsadasO^w#g /var/www/build.int/protected/config/params.php

Comment: Despite I have not solved my problem, I need to award the bounty due to SO rules. You tried most hard, so its yours.

Comment: Let's try to finish this anyway. Do you mean that it's producing the output but not changing the file by itself? that's because we haven't added `-i` flag to sed (""replace in place"), for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about any jenkins plugin which works that way , but I needed to know if its possible to make sed ignore the special characters using this :

[sed with special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980857/sed-with-special-characters)

And I suppose you must be using a Password Parameter with your parameterized job, which hides the password.