# replace special character [ and ] including . using sed

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I would like to replace the `[sample].` with space in all my document.Could someone let me know how can I do this.I tried the below command but it doesn't work.thanks.

```
sed -I 's/[sample]./ /g' filename.txt
```

due to use of `[]` and `.` I am having different output. 
I really appreciate your help

Comment: Have you tried escaping those spexial characters by putting a backslash before them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What special characters must be escaped in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace paired square brackets with other syntax with sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10646418/608639), [What characters do I need to escape when using sed in a sh script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32907/56041), [Escape a string for a sed replace pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/407523/608639), [Which characters need to be escaped in Bash? How do we know it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15783701/608639), [sed with special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5980857/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the special characters with `\`. Also, there's no `-I` option, the option to update the file in place is `-i`.

```
sed -i 's/\[sample\]\./ /g' filename.txt
```

Comment: Looks like you're still missing the backslashes before `[` and `]`. And why are you grepping for `sample` but replacing `VA_REPOSITORY`?

Comment: You can use `grep -F` to tell it that the pattern is a fixed string, not a regexp, then you don't need to escape anything there.

Comment: You're also missing the filename argument to `grep`: `grep -l -F '[sample].` *.txt | ...`

Answer (score 0):

This is really simple my Friend . lets see I have task.
Replace all occurrence of string #%$2jh//238720//31223 with $2//23872031223 in /home/bob/data.txt file.

now the solution is there ever you see special character just replace is with \ just like i do as below.

sed -i 's/#%$2jh//238720//31223/$2//23872031223/g' /home/bob/data.txt